# Kubuntu 14.04 + kdm sound works only when logged in as root

Tags: sound, root

I am NOT advocating logging in as root.  But I found that sound works when I do.  When I log in as a normal user- no sound, no mixer, no hint that the machine even has an audio device.

Where do I even begin to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Please help us help you buy providing the output of `groups <username>` where , <username> is the user name that has no audio.

Answer (score 0):

You could try insuring that your user is a member of the audio group.

`sudo useradd -G {group-name} username.`

source: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-add-user-to-group/

Comment: I added the user to audio.  Still no sound though.  BTW:  How do I get a newline here?

Comment: Have you tired creating a new user and seeing if the problem exists in that profile? Questions about how the site works should be asked on meta.askubuntu.com.